# Jackson Serialization to Array

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

I have the following class:

```
class People
{
    private List<String> people = new ArrayList<>();

    public People()
    {
        people.add("Jhon");
        people.add("Rose");
    }
}
```

it is serialized using jackson to `{"people":["Jhon","Rose"]}`

I would like to serialize to `["Jhon","Rose"]` without custom serializers.

any suggestion?

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to get the field and serialize that instead of the wrapper object:

```
People people = new People();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(people.getPeople());
```

If that's not an option, a [Converter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) may be simpler than a custom serializer:

```
class PeopleToList extends StdConverter<People, List<String>> {
    @Override public List<String> convert(People people) {
        return people.getPeople();
    }
}
```

and specify to use that:

```
@JsonSerialize(converter = PeopleToList.class)
class People {
```